# Pytorch Custom Data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to build a GAN that will generate only a single digit of mnist data. I have custom data and figured out how to give custom data as input to the GAN but What should i return in len function if i do not have a csv file with the number of images i have in the dataset?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import torch 
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from skimage import io
```

## In[3]:

```
class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
   def __init__(self,root_dir,transform=None):
     self.root_dir = root_dir
     self.transform = transform
   
   def __len__(self):
     return len(self.root_dir)

   def __getitem__(self,idx):
     img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir)
     image = io.imread(img_path)
     # y_label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx,1]
     if self.transform:
        image = self.transform(image)
    # if self.target_transform(image):
    #     label = self.target_transform(label)
    return image
```

Comment: So here `__getitem__` always returns the same element?